# Twig date mktime

Tags: php, symfony, date, twig, mktime

Is there an equivalent function in Twig which matches the PHP function **mktime**?  I am trying to convert the following code to Twig

```
$this->headTitle( date('F jS Y' , mktime( 0 , 0 , 0 , $this->month , $this->day , $this->year )) );
```

The **$this** variables are all **int** as you would expect ( YYYY MM DD )

Comment: Do the conversion in the php code and pass the result into the twig in the normal way `$twig->render('index.html', array('mydate' => $mydate);`

Comment: `{{ (year ~ '-' ~ month ~ '-' ~ day)|date('F jS Y') }}` would give you a formatted date string of your variables (providing they are "year", "month' and "day")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always write your own functions and add it to Twig with [TwigExtensions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html), eg:

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('my_mktime', array($this, 'myMktime')),
    );
}

public function myMktime($month, $day, $year)
{
    retrun \mktime( 0 , 0 , 0 , $month , $day , $year );
}
```

But I don't understand what are you trying to do.. Twig is for View (display output), but your are trying to do some logic with this lines - `$this->headTitle( date('F jS Y' , mktime( 0 , 0 , 0 , $this->month , $this->day , $this->year )) );`...

Comment: I am trying to include the date in the <title> tag.